# Как сделать input многострочным и с ресайзом?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать именно этот `input` многострочным и с ресайзом, как у `textarea`? Ну или хотябы, что нибудь одно из этого.

```
<input type=" textarea" id="edititeminputcomment">
<style>
   input#edititeminputcomment {
      min-height: 200px;
   }
</style>
```

html не валидный, но `<input type=" textarea"` менять нельзя.

Comment: `<input type=" textarea">` не существует в природе. Используйте либо `<input type="text">`, либо `<textarea>`

Comment: Вопрос был в другом. Не важно что там textarea, input же существует

Comment: Вам не приходило в голову, что браузер рендерит контрол именно от типа?